# PowerShell ssh wont stop asking for the password to the key I installed

Tags: windows, ssh, ssh-keys

I'm still being asked for my key password on login from a PowerShell session (Windows 10).

These it turned out are the wrong param:

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no
```

or

```
ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no"
```

I swear I had a perfect ignore parameter that was working but I lost it.

I want to get ssh to ignore my installed keys.

I have a key installed in the ssh keyring that I used to access a critical device. The key is password protected (which is causing issues logging in to other systems that do not use the key).

Comment: This could be what you are looking for: https://serverfault.com/questions/130346/ssh-use-only-my-password-ignore-my-ssh-key-dont-prompt-me-for-a-passphrase

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh Aaayyy! Thats the one!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[As explained here](https://serverfault.com/questions/130346/ssh-use-only-my-password-ignore-my-ssh-key-dont-prompt-me-for-a-passphrase), in order to ignore your ssh keys you added, use this parameter to ignore those keys for the login:

```
ssh -o PreferredAuthentications=password host.example.org
```

Answer (score 6):

`StrictHostKeyChecking` has nothing to do with your private key's password. It checks if the server's cryptographic fingerprint is the same as the one that is stored locally for that server. Remember, the first time you connected, it asked you if the fingerprint was ok? That's now stored in ~/.ssh/known_hosts and that's what it compares against. This is to avoid MITM attacks, without having a full chain of trust like SSL/TLS has for example.

Now, to avoid entering your key password there are basically two options:

- Delete the password on your key (`ssh-keygen -p` and  don't enter a password) , which is not terribly secure, so the better option:
- Use `ssh-agent` to manage the key

Personally I've never worked with ssh-agent in Powershell, but Microsoft [says the following](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_keymanagement) about it:

```
# By default the ssh-agent service is disabled. Allow it to be manually started for the next step to work.
# Make sure you're running as an Administrator.
Get-Service ssh-agent | Set-Service -StartupType Manual

# Start the service
Start-Service ssh-agent

# This should return a status of Running
Get-Service ssh-agent

# Now load your key files into ssh-agent
ssh-add ~\.ssh\id_ed25519
```

Comment: OK that looks familiar because thats how I added my key to the keyring - the goal I have is ssh to ignore that key I added to the ssh keyring for the few times I need to ignore it, .... but at the same time not remove the key from the keyring so that I can still use the key to get into the critical device.

Comment: I was saying an ssh parameter wasnt working... it was the wrong one. "-o PreferredAuthentications=password" is the one that causes ssh to ignore keyring and let you login without also providing the password to the key. A commenter gave me the answer so you probably know this one, you should answer my question if you want

Comment: Nah, I'm good. I don't go for the whole gambler's fallacy thing. We'll just leave this here as a notice to other people that it's important to ask the _right_ question.

Comment: It is important to ask the right question to get the right answer but I imagine with technical issues many people have supposed a parameter would do one thing rather than the other and supposed that that parameter was the issue. The asker still has the same problem at the end of the day which is what this platform helps to answer. In addition, I did explain what I was trying to do but got answers that were addressing the parameter I was trying to use with it instead. Not sure what this has to do with gambler's fallacy.

Comment: ... which is why I'm not going to update my answer

Answer (score 1):

(Note: I concur with mtak that `StrictHostKeyChecking` is completely irrelevant to the selection and use of *client* key(s).)

OpenSSH (which is what Windows 10 up supplies a port of) does not have a 'keyring', but it does have a directory where default files may be located *and* a process (ssh-agent) which is also tried by default.

If you mean you don't want to use key(s) from your *agent process*, specify `-o IdentitiesOnly=yes`. However, once a key is loaded in the agent you aren't prompted again for the password, which doesn't match your description of your problem. This option is more commonly needed when a host imposes a limit on authentication trials, and the agent has so many keys loaded that trying them all exhausts the host's limit before hitting the correct one for that host.

If you mean you have default file(s) `%userprofile%/.ssh/id_{rsa,dsa,ecdsa,ed25519}` (or maybe their `_sk` or `-cert` variants; I don't know if the Windows port supports `sk`) and you don't want to use it or (all of) them for a particular connection, specify (only) the file(s) you do want with `-i` or `-o IdentityFile=`.

You could have either or both of these apply automatically for a particular hostname by putting it/them in a `Host` or `Match` block in your `%userprofile%/.ssh/config` file. See [the man page](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config). However, it sounds like what you really want is to move the special (and password-protected) key for the 'critical device' to a *nondefault* name so it is not used for 'normal' connections, but configured so it is used (only) for the hostname(s?) of the specific device.